# link_to user_url(:id) Users Show Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

How can I dynamically link_to a user's show page (Rails) I currently have this

```
<%=link_to 'Profile', user_url(:id)%>
```

but the User id is not dynamically passing through

Comment: I assume you are `iterating` a piece of code.Please post the code of the view file which contains the `link_to` line

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the user object it self, if you have a user object called `@user` just do this

```
<%= link_to 'Profile', @user %>
```

If you only have the `id`, then

```
<%= link_to 'Profile', user_path(id) %>
```

This of course will change depending on your routes definition.